# Simplify $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{p^k}{k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, z-transform

Note that this is not a infinite sum like $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{p^k}{k!}=e^p$, but a finite one.

Or, simplify the infinite sum $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{p^k}{(k+n)!}$ may also help.

Maybe it can be solved by $Z$-transformation?

Comment: It is unlikely that a exact formula exists. What do you need the simpler formula for?

Comment: Have a look at my answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4809120/how-to-justify-this-estimation/4809448#4809448

Answer (score 3):

MathWorld calls this the *exponential sum function*, and notes that it can be expressed in terms of the incomplete gamma function. Indeed,
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{p^k}{k!} = \frac{e^p \Gamma(n+1,p)}{\Gamma(n+1)},$$
taken from https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialSumFunction.html.